# Can't get my dual monitor settings to "stick"

Tags: multiple-monitors, kubuntu, kde

I'm running Kubuntu 12.10.  I have a nVidia GT-430 video card with a large 27" 2560x1550 monitor hooked up with dual-link DVI and a smaller 21" 1920x1080 monitor hooked up with HDMI.  Before I log on, the login manager appears to be using both monitors separately (the list of userids is spread across both monitors), but as soon as I log in, it makes them clones of each other.  I have to go in and change the "Position" of the smaller monitor from "Clone of" to "Left of".  It doesn't matter whether I click "Save as Default" or not, I still have to reset it every time.

I look in `.kde/share/config/startupconfig` and I see what looks like the right commands:

```
# krandrrc Display ApplyOnStartup false
krandrrc_display_applyonstartup=true
# krandrrc Display StartupCommands ''
krandrrc_display_startupcommands='xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --pos 1920x0 --mode 2560x1440 --refresh 59.9506
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 0x0 --mode 1920x1080 --refresh 60
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --primary'
# krandrrc [Screen0]
# krandrrc [Screen1]
# krandrrc [Screen2]
# krandrrc [Screen3]
```

Note the `--pos 1920x0` for DVI-I-1, which is correct.  Similarly, `.kde/share/config/krandrrc` also appears to have the correct offset of the big screen to put it to the right of the small screen:

```
[Display]
ApplyOnStartup=true
StartupCommands=xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --pos 1920x0 --mode 2560x1440 --refresh 59.9506\nxrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 0x0 --mode 1920x1080 --refresh 60\nxrandr --output DVI-I-1 --primary

[Screen_0]
OutputsUnified=false
UnifiedRect=0,0,0,0
UnifiedRotation=1

[Screen_0_Output_DVI-I-1]
Active=true
Rect=1920,0,2560,1440
RefreshRate=59.9505500793457
Rotation=1

[Screen_0_Output_HDMI-0]
Active=true
Rect=0,0,1920,1080
RefreshRate=60
Rotation=1

[Screen_0_Output_HDMI-1]
Active=true
Rect=0,0,1920,1080
RefreshRate=60
Rotation=1
```

How can I get this working the way it's supposed to?  I'd like to get this working because in a month or two I'm going to buy a second GT-430 and a second 27" monitor, and I'd like to have this all working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a perfect solution by any means, but I seem to have a work-around - I brought up the `nvidia-settings` program, and clicked on "X Server Display Configuration", made sure it was showing the layout I wanted, and clicked "Save to X Configuration File", and saved it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Credit to http://www.muktware.com/articles/3081/how-set-dual-monitor-kde-nvidia-settings#.UPBmByZQAx4

Answer (score 2):

This is my workaround.

```
nano ~/.kde4/Autostart/setupscreens.sh
```

fill with the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=$(sed '3q;d' $HOME/.kde4/share/config/krandrrc)

${foo:16}
```

save (ctrl-o) and exit (ctrl-x)

now make it executable

```
chmod +x ~/.kde4/Autostart/setupscreens.sh
```

What it does is run the xrandr command generated by the system settings GUI when you setup your screen. I have no idea why for many this is not properly executed on login but for me this was a simple fix that works if I change my setup in the future using the system settings.